# post_title in save_post action

Tags: post-meta, title, save-post

I use `save_post` action to save meta field and to check if post title is set. So I check the value returned by `empty($post->post_title)` but I get true also if I set the title.

Comment: `false` should be the right value. `empty()` returns `false` when your title is __not__ empty.

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong, I get true also if the title is not empty.

Comment: Could you post a little more code?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the surrounding code, it is hard to tell what the problem might be,
but you said you checked the `$post` variable. Maybe the `$post` variable is not set properly, the `save_post` action only gives you the post id:

```
function get_post_title($post_id) {
  $post = get_post($post_id);

  if (empty($post->post_title)) {
    // No title set, put in your code
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'get_post_title');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `save_post` action hook fires before post data is saved to the database at this point, the post title might not be set in the `$post` object. Instead, you should use the `$_POST` data directly to check if the title is set.

```
add_action('save_post', 'my_save_post_function');

function my_save_post_function($post_id) {
    // Check if the post is being saved for the first time
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the post title is set in the $_POST data
    if (isset($_POST['post_title']) && !empty($_POST['post_title'])) {
        // The post title is set
        // Perform your meta field saving logic here
    } else {
        // The post title is not set
        // You can handle this case as needed
    }
}
```